# Consulta MySQL que retorne apenas registros que iniciem com determinado trecho

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um campo em minha tabela o qual os dados inseridos são tratados diretamente no PHP. O valor desse campo é concatenado para fazer alusão ao primeiro registro com o inicio semelhante.

Exemplo:

- primeiro registro é inserido com código 1;
- o registro que fizer referência a ele, terá código 1.1, 1.2 e assim por diante.;

O problema é que na hora da consulta, se houverem registros 11.1, ele acaba agrupando com o registro 1.

Podem me ajudar nessa questão? Preciso retornar os valores que façam parte apenas da primeira parte da casa decimal.

Trecho do SQL:

```
AND Codigo LIKE '".$Codigo'."%' ";
```

Valeu pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem sua pergunta, vamos lá.
O que você precisa?
Ex.:
Campo
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
...
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
...
11.1
11.2
11.3
11.4

Esse são os campos da tabela, o que você passa para ser pesquisado?
o que você precisa encontrar?
Me passe esses dados para tentar te ajudar